# How to Make Watch app free for subscriber

Tags: android, ios, wear-os, apple-watch

I've built an android and an iOS mobile app. I'm planning to release an watch app for WatchOS and WearOS. My plan is that the watch apps will be paid for normal users, but if someone is a paid subscriber from my mobile app, it will make the watch app free for them. How can I achieve this functionality?